# Problem connecting with SQL database in VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to connect with SQL Server Database using VB.Net.  In Datasource of Binding Source, I selected 'Add project datasource' Clicked 'Database and New Connection in Choose Connection Wizard.

In New Connection, what to select 'SQL Server' or SQL server Database?

I tried both but when Tested Connection, it failed to connect.

Also, what type of password to be chosen, Windows based or SQL Server based?

Please guide.

Thanks
Furqan

Comment: It depends on where your SQL server is located, how it's been set up.  Someone should have provided you with login details?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your database is located, but if it is the default SQL express installed with Visual Studio your servername should be `.\sqlexpress` and authentication should be windows based.

Answer (score 0):

follow this guide, this is what i used when i was just starting out and by the time your finished you'll know everything there is to know about sql databases and how to manipulate their information:

Part 1 you don't need if you already have mysql downloaded...

Part 2 explains how to set the server up correctly,

Part 3-6 explains how to set up your vb.net application and sql database correctly,

Part 7 explains how to make an installer for your finished Application.

And theres example codes along the way!

---

[Part 2](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-2)

[Part 3](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-3)

[Part 4](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-4)

[Part 5](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-5)

[Part 6](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-6)

[Part 7](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-7)

Hope This Helps!